# Pandas come back form groupBy

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

My goal is to take data and interpolate missing values based on specific column and specific type
I achieved this goal but I have trouble to coming back to the shape of data frame before interpolation.

```
data = [
    {"type": "Car", "avg_speed": 30, "max_speed": 200},
    {"type": "Car", "avg_speed": 20, "max_speed": 100},
    {"type": "Car", "avg_speed": 25, "max_speed": None},
    {"type": "Plane", "avg_speed": 300, "max_speed": 2000},
    {"type": "Plane", "avg_speed": 200, "max_speed": 1000},
    {"type": "Plane", "avg_speed": 250, "max_speed": None}
]


df = pd.DataFrame(data)
print(df)
post_interp = df.groupby("type").apply(lambda x: x.set_index(
    'avg_speed').sort_index().interpolate(method='index'))
print(post_interp)
```

first print:

```
    type  avg_speed  max_speed
0    Car         30      200.0
1    Car         20      100.0
2    Car         25        NaN
3  Plane        300     2000.0
4  Plane        200     1000.0
5  Plane        250        NaN
```

second print:

```
                  type  max_speed
type  avg_speed
Car   20           Car      100.0
      25           Car      150.0
      30           Car      200.0
Plane 200        Plane     1000.0
      250        Plane     1500.0
      300        Plane     2000.0
```

I would like to return to shape of data frame in print 1 with interpolated values.

Comment: You want to assign the new `max_speed` and `avg_speed` columns to the original DataFrame?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `group_keys=False` to [`DataFrame.groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) for avoid duplicated index and last add [`DataFrame.reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html):

```
post_interp = (df.groupby("type", group_keys=False)
                 .apply(lambda x: x.set_index('avg_speed')
                                   .sort_index()
                                   .interpolate(method='index'))
                 .reset_index())
```

Another solution with double `reset_index`:

```
post_interp = (df.groupby("type")
                 .apply(lambda x: x.set_index('avg_speed')
                                   .sort_index()
                                   .interpolate(method='index'))
                 .reset_index(level=0, drop=True)
                 .reset_index())
```

Or you can create index before `groupby`:

```
post_interp = (df.set_index('avg_speed')
                 .sort_index()
                 .groupby("type", group_keys=False)
                 .apply(lambda x: x.interpolate(method='index'))
                 .reset_index())
print(post_interp)
   avg_speed   type  max_speed
0         20    Car      100.0
1         25    Car      150.0
2         30    Car      200.0
3        200  Plane     1000.0
4        250  Plane     1500.0
5        300  Plane     2000.0
```

Last if necessary same order of columns add [`DataFrame.reindex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html):

```
post_interp = post_interp.reindex(df.columns, axis=1)
print(post_interp)
    type  avg_speed  max_speed
0    Car         20      100.0
1    Car         25      150.0
2    Car         30      200.0
3  Plane        200     1000.0
4  Plane        250     1500.0
5  Plane        300     2000.0
```